# Excel Save As Button Macro

Tags: vba, excel

I would like to create a VB "Save As" macro for Excel that would utilize the data from cell `B7`,`B5` and `=NOW` as the file name. This new file name would then be saved to a particular directory. (Ex. User clicks "Save" button. `File name = (B5)ABCD_(B7)EFGH_=NOW` is created and then saved to a directory of my choosing.

I have found scripts that offer some of the singular options, but have had no luck finding or creating a script of my own with these options. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: No luck, eh? What have you tried exactly?

Answer (score 2):

You need to substitute for the invalid characters in the filename (they can't contain `/` or `:`) with periods or something else.

```
Sub DateFile()
    Dim str As String
    str = Range("B5").Value & "ABCD_" & Range("B7").Value & "EFGH" & Now()
    str = Replace(str, "/", ".")
    str = Replace(str, ":", ".")
    ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs (str)
End Sub
```

This can then be integrated into your push button code.

Comment: What Now() return (when converted to a string) depend on local PC  date time settings.  To get better control use `Format(now(), "FormatString")`, where "FormatString" specifies the format you require, eg "YYYY_MM_DD" would give 2011_06_02 for today

Comment: To achieve the "saved to a directory of my choosing" add `str = "PathOfYourChoice" & str` (unless path is included in cell `B5`)

Comment: Filename can't contain `\ * " ? < > |` either! (Unless @Erik is using a non-Windows OS in which case the list may differ.) In any case, if you're gonna screen for some of these characters, then you should really screen for all of them.

Comment: @Jean-François Corbett I opted to screen for those because those were the characters in the date/time that was returned by `Now()` in my locale.

Comment: @Jean-François Corbett Ah, but I suppose that one of the other cells could contain one of those other invalid characters.  I see your point.

Comment: @jonsca: aha, now I understand why you singled out `/` and `:`.